# Swing GUI IntelliJ IDEA Macbook

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing, intellij-idea

I just started out with learning Java in uni and we're allowed to work with both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA. Our professor gave us a not fully completed code for PACMAN and we're to complete it individually and add a few things as well.

The problem is that the GUI/Swing does not work (well, it opens, but then it rains errors). Our professor told us that as she does not have a Mac, she cannot help us and we should figure it out ourselves. I must say I worked myself through Google the past couple of days and for instance installed Tomcat through Homebrew (did not change anything sadly).

Macbook specs: MacBook Pro 2016, 10.12.4.

IntelliJ IDEA specs: 2017.1.2, UI designer is installed.

Problem: running the app does not work. I tried in both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA (no success).

Hereby the [error log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-JRYx5T2hp6YVFwaE16Qkl0eGc) and the [files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-JRYx5T2hp6TnBQTEo0NzMzWkE) itself.

Comment: over 100 pages error code? please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You don't need Tomcat to run this game. The log is not complete, but it looks like the problem is related to playing the game sounds. `nomNom` field is `null` at `game/GameSounds.java:61`. As the sample you provided works fine on Windows, there is probably something specific to handling audio on Mac. Start with logging any exceptions at `game/GameSounds.java:43` to see if the sounds were initialized properly. Then add checks for `null` at the places where NPE is thrown so that you can continue running.

Comment: @halfer for instance

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok, thank you! I'll try and see from there on!

Comment: @P.J.Meisch my apologies. I'll replace it with a shortened error log!

Comment: This code is awful. The GUI class extends JApplet (are you testing this in a web page?), which is a top-level container, but then it also creates a JFrame which is also a top-level container. So it has a top-level container iside a top-level container. It overrides paint() which you should never do, especially on a top-level container, paintComponent() is more appropriate. I am just getting started....

Comment: I kind of have it working on my Mac, still working... To get you going "sounds" are loaded from the classpath with getResource() so put the sounds directory on your classpath. Images are loaded with a relative file name, so move the "img" directory on the same level as the "src" directory. There is no need to have GUI extend Applet, remove that.

Comment: @Michael thank you so much! I'll try and change the things you suggested!!